# Bridging TinyMCE js and Wordpress PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce

I'm updating my wordpress plugin to use a custom TinyMCE button. From inside the TinyMCE button javascript, I'd like to interact with wordpress data--ie set custom post options inside the plugin setting page, then access those values inside the TinyMCE js script.

Can I invoke my php plugin functions from inside the TinyMCE button handler code (which is javascript)?

Is there a bridge I can use?

For Clarification:

As part of my plugin installation process, users are instructed to go to the Plugin settings page, and input some data. This data is normally stored and read using Wordpress Plugin API hooks: `get_option` and `set_option` This is part of my original plugin and works fine.

I am now adding a TinyMCE button, and when I click it, an HTML page is shown, that has an html `textarea`. This part also works fine.

However, I'd like to Fill the `textarea` with data via the `get_option` Wordpress Plugin call, but I can't figure out how to access the API.

Another acceptable solution would be to pass that data into the TinyMCE script, and injest it that way.

Or to have the TinyMCE button script invoke a method in my PHP plugin script that reads and returns that data back into the TinyMCE button script.

Comment: can you clarify me - you looking for example to invoke your plugin functionality from tinymce button script right (so i asume you have created tinymce button)?

Comment: Yes, I have created the Tinymce Button. What I'm looking to do is access Wordpress's plugin API from inside TinyMCE script. If a user installs our plugin, there is some settings they specify as part of the plugin configuration. Those are stored via `set_option()` in wordpress plugin API. I'd like to read that data inside the TinyMCE page script.

Answer (score 1):

I have integrated buttons to TinyMCE with WordPress functionality, let me know if [this material](http://devwp.eu/add-a-tinymce-button-to-wordpress-post-editor%EF%BB%BF%EF%BB%BF/) would add some context with code samples to your use case.

Comment: Thanks Mario. Unfortunately it wasn't helpful. I already have a TinyMCE button that shows up in the WYSIWYG editor. I'm actually trying to access Wordpress API from inside TinyMCE script.

Comment: Use the admin_ajax hooks for that purpose, invoke AJAX calls from the plugin with an action registered there. More on AJAX calls - http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins and another sample with AJAX from me - http://devwp.eu/overcome-the-wordpress-autosave-limitations/ - for autosave using jQuery AJAX calls over WP function

Comment: BOOM. That's the ticket. Would you mind editing your answer to include this information and I'll mark it as accepted!

Comment: sure thing, go ahead

Answer (score 1):

Sample of mce button code

```
(function() {
var each = tinymce.each;
tinymce.PluginManager.requireLangPack('grid');
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.FoundationGridPlugin', {
    init : function(ed, url) {
        var t = this; t.editor = ed;
        imageUrl = url + '/../images/grid.png';
    },

    createControl : function(n, cm) {

        var t = this, c, ed = t.editor;

        if (n == 'grid') {
            c = cm.createButton(n, {
                title : 'grid.title', 
                scope : t, 
                image:imageUrl,
                onclick : function() {
                    ed.execCommand("mceShowGridContainer", false, false);
                }

            });
            return c;
        }
    },

    execCommand: function(cmd, ui, type) {
        var ed = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
        var url = this.url;
        switch (cmd) {
            case "mceShowGridContainer":
                jQuery.post(ajaxurl, {action:'grid_action_ajax'}, function(html){
                     // some code here
                });
            break;
        }   
    },

    getInfo : function() {
        return {
            longname : 'Foundation Grid Generator',
            author   : 'Oleg Butuzov;',
            authorurl: 'http://made.com.ua',
            infourl  : 'http://made.com.ua',
            version  : '2.0'
        };
    }
});

tinymce.PluginManager.add('grid', tinymce.plugins.FoundationGridPlugin);
})();
```

and here is code you actualy need...

```
onclick : function() {
    ed.execCommand("mceShowGridContainer", false, false);
}
```

which runs

```
case "mceShowGridContainer":
       jQuery.post(ajaxurl, {action:'wpse73257_grid_action_ajax'}, function(html){
             // some code here
       });
break;
```

now you can simply add ajax_action that wil interact with your script

```
 add_action('wp_ajax_wpse73257_grid_action_ajax', 'wpse73257_grid_action_ajax');
 function wpse73257_grid_action_ajax(){
   //do something and show something
 exit;
}
```